# Some MP4 not playing in Chromecast

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I try to play video from my phone on Chromecast. Some MP4 videos are playing and some were not playing. After loading the media I am seeing the following error. Can any one help on this?

11-06 14:30:15.572: V/CastSampleActivity(6198): Getting channel after session start

11-06 14:30:15.572: V/CastSampleActivity(6198): Creating and attaching Message Stream

11-06 14:30:15.582: V/CastSampleActivity(6198): Loading selected media on device

11-06 14:30:15.582: V/CastSampleActivity(6198): cmd created, player state = null

11-06 14:30:15.582: V/CastSampleActivity(6198): Loading selected media Completed

11-06 14:30:16.763: E/MediaProtocolMessageStream(6198): error parsing message: {"type":"RESPONSE","cmd_id":1,"status":{"error":{"domain":"ramp","code":-2},"event_sequence":3931}} org.json.JSONException: No value for state

Error on Receiver:

```
[104.266s] [cast.receiver.ChannelOverWebSocket] Sending message: ["ramp",{"cmd_id":6,"type":"RESPONSE","status":{"event_sequence":145,"state":0,"content_id":"http://192.168.0.162:1234/storage/emulated/0/Video%20Highlight/Islandia.mp4","current_time":0,"duration":null,"volume":1,"muted":false,"time_progress":false,"title":"title"}}] from ws://localhost:8008/session?2
```

cast_receiver.js:66
 [105.013s] [cast.receiver.RemoteMedia] Received error event from media element

cast_receiver.js:66
 [105.030s] [cast.receiver.ChannelOverWebSocket] Sending message: ["ramp",{"cmd_id":1,"type":"RESPONSE","status":{"event_sequence":146,"error":{"domain":"ramp","code":-2}}}] from ws://localhost:8008/session?2

cast_receiver.js:66
 [105.066s] [cast.receiver.RemoteMedia] getStatus

Comment: What does the receiver's log show?

Comment: Log on Receiver:  [105.013s] [cast.receiver.RemoteMedia] Received error event from media element
 
cast_receiver.js:66
 [105.030s] [cast.receiver.ChannelOverWebSocket] Sending message: ["ramp",{"cmd_id":1,"type":"RESPONSE","status":{"event_sequence":146,"error":{"domain":"ramp","code":-2}}}] from ws://localhost:8008/session?2
 
cast_receiver.js:66
 [105.066s] [cast.receiver.RemoteMedia] getStatus

Answer (score 0):

Problem was not with chromecast. Some MP4 video was not loading in chrome. After I try with webm format the video is getting loaded.